# IC design/verification with Python

Tags: python, fpga, hdl, register-transfer-level, asic

I see a lot of jobs in this field asking for Perl and Python scripting experience.  Very little C programming if any.  Where HDL is the main focus (verilog,, VHDL) along with digital system design knowledge.

Is Python generally used in these job roles as an industry standard or as an "unofficial standard"?  I have little experience for Python and what I do is for Math/Science applications, its most useful application.

Does anyone have much experience for Python in this field of work and know whether it is entirely beneficial to license based software/tools?

Answer (score 3):

Python is used as a glue logic programming language in many areas.

Pros:

- It's a scripting language
- It can be used to write real programs
- It has OOP features
- C libraries can be called
- It's more powerful than Bash scripts
- It works on Linux and Windows
- A big standard library

Some popular testing environments are Python based:

- [VUnit](https://github.com/LarsAsplund/vunit)
- [cocotb](https://github.com/potentialventures/cocotb)
- [myHDL](http://www.myhdl.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Python and Perl are [popular](http://redmonk.com/sogrady/2015/07/01/language-rankings-6-15/) in general , not only for the "HDL industry". If I had to name a "standard" scripting language I would say [TCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl) since it's so commonly supported by EDA tools. I would much rather have Python scripting in these tools but unfortunately that's not the case.